# Encoding a string of numbers (recursively?)

Tags: python, string, recursion

I've been looking at this sample problem for some time and can't figure out how to solve it in Python, Pythonically:

Let's say I have a string of numbers, `data = "124136"`

walking through the string, left to right, integers can correspond to a letter of the alphabet (e.g. 1=`a`, 12=`l`, 2=`b`, 24=`x`)

I want to count how many possible valid letter encodings there are (i.e. how many different sequences of one- or two-digit chunks can be made stepping through the string, with each chunk being <= 26). How, in Python, do you loop through that string and look at each digit and each pair? I'm looking for sensible, human-readable Python, not necessarily the slickest way.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, this is not a free coding service. Good luck!

Comment: Gather next decimals until the result would be >26. Always add the first (single) number to your to-do list. Only if it's a `1` or `2` you can check the next one to be in range, and then add that as well. Sounds like a perfect job for recursion.

Comment: @usr2564301 In my understanding, Python doesn't really like to use indices, so asking for data[i+1] isn't really considered very pythonic, no?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that all of your inputs can be converted?  A `0` preceded by any digit except `1` or `2` can't be uniquely coded.

Comment: @ikebukuru you're not asking to iterate a string character by character, what you're asking is, while iterating, to also check any two consecutive characters if they can be parsed to a number < 26. This is not a one "liner" or two. Second, when you come up with such a question without showing your effort, you come up as "do my HW for me" type of guy, which I'm sure you're not.

Comment: @Prune absolutely! 0 preceded would have to be skipped... i.e. 012 would have to skip the 0, but 102 would be 1 and 10.

Comment: Not quite -- you can't skip a leading 0, or you map both "012" and "12" to the same encoding.

Comment: "102" cannot map the leading digit alone: the `1` has to take the `0` with it, or you're left with "02", and encounter the same problem.

Comment: @alfasin exactly! My effort isn't worth showing, however, as it's just brute-force and doesn't actually solve it at all - my thinking was take them by pairs and then look at each digit and then the pair...

`[data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]` but that yields `['12', '41', '36']` ... in which case I'm not capturing the possibility of '24' being an option in any sane way.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: @ikebukuru I would split the problem to two: (1) generate all the substring of length 1 and of length 2. and (2) for each such substring, called `num`, try to check if: `int(num) < 26` and if so, add it to a result-list. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sliding_window](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.sliding_window) function and check all combinations(there will be only three combinations possible) within the window

```
from toolz.itertoolz import sliding_window
d=set()
data = "124136"
for i in list(sliding_window(2, data)):
    if 1<=int(i[0])<=26:
        d.add(i[0])
    if 1<=int(i[1])<=26:
        d.add(i[1])
    if 1<=int(i[0]+i[1])<=26:
        d.add(i[0]+i[1])
print(d) # {'1', '12', '13', '2', '24', '3', '4', '6'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a coding service.  However, we can help with algorithms.

To count the quantity of solutions available, you'll need to follow *all* legal paths.  I recommend a recursive routine with backtracking and memoization (dynamic programming).

```
def code_ct(s):

    # Base case: short string
    # if string length is
    0: return 0
    1: return 1 unless digit is '0'; then return failure

    # Otherwise, recur for the normal case

    # Count 1-digit encoding branch:
    # If this digit is 0, return 0
    # Otherwise, consume this digit; recur on s[1:]
    one_digit = count_end(s[1:])

    # If the first *two* digits form a legal encoding, count that branch as well
    # Consume two digits (to be 'j'-'z') and handle the remaining string.
    if 10 <= int(str[:1]) <= 26:
        two_digit = code_ct(str[2:])

    total_ct = one_digit + two_digit
    return total_ct
```

Properly implemented, this should give you the legal quantity of encodings.
If you need the actual encodings, you'll need to instrument the return values with the encoding or the 1/2-digit pieces, accumulating the solution as you crawl back up the stack.

You also still need to handle error cases, check failure as you see fit, and ... left as an exercise for the student.

For any long inputs, this will be *much* faster if you implement memoization as well.

Comment: Thanks @Prune - DP and memos is what I was looking at to get me to O(n) eventually for sure. I'm just having trouble Pythonically splitting the string though I see what you're doing there with the string slicing. It's a trickier problem to code than it is to think through for sure.

Comment: `l = set()
def count_ways(data):
    global l
    if len(data) == 0:
        return
    one_dig = int(data[:1])
    two_digs = int(data[:2])
    if (one_dig > 0):
        l.add(one_dig)
    if (10 <= two_digs <= 26):
        l.add(two_digs)
    count_ways(data[1:])

count_ways(data)
print(len(l))`

The poor man's recursive way using a set and slices from what you gave, I came up with this.